# What to do with users who does not mark the answer as correct and keeps the question open?

Tags: discussion

I have seen that users does not mark any answer as correct to their questions. I want know the reason as to why do they do that? And I would also like to know what can be done so that the questions does not remain open?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions also get removed from the "unanswered" list if they have an upvoted answer - if there is a case when the original poster has commented with "this works for me" type of comment, then feel free to follow up with a comment suggesting they flag it as the accepted answer

Comment: But what if the OP does not respond at all for days?

Comment: Upvote the most suitable answer?