# Unanswered questions that solved the problem

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

In a related question [here](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/q/271/18061), @RowlandShaw answered

> if there is a case when the original poster has commented with "this works for > me" type of comment, then feel free to follow up with a comment suggesting
>   they flag it as the accepted answer

At present we have 85% of questions answered and we can do more than that. Questions with 3 or more upvotes are marked as answered. There are many cases where the OP has commented an answer that it worked but has not marked it()some have not even upvoted. I feel that we could have this place to highlight such questions so they don't remain open. Take this [answer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/13808/18061) as an example, commented as useful but 0 upvotes.

---

### How it will work?

I am adding a community wiki post as an answers can be listed. There answers must be

- **answer said to be worked by the person who asked the question**
- OP has been asked in a followup comments to mark it as an answer but with no response for more than 3 days.
- answer does not have 3 upvotes

As soon as it reaches 3 upvotes it can be removed except the last one so that it can serve as an example. The last one can be striken out instead.

---

Considering that we are only going to list out answers that were useful to the one who asked I think it is legal.

If moderators feel this as illegal or as an unnecessary step, I will remove it.